# Huge memory consumption during compilation when passing constexpr by const reference

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, g++

Compilation of the following code with g++ consumes a surprisingly big amount of memory (over 5gb).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#define N 100000

struct A {
    int tab[N];
    constexpr A(): tab{} {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) tab[i] = i;
    }
};

struct B {
    int tab[N];
    constexpr B(const A& a): tab{} {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) tab[i] = a.tab[N-1-i] * 2;
    }
};

constexpr A a;
constexpr B b(a);
 
int main(){ std::cout << b.tab[N-5]; }
```

It seems that it is caused by passing a `const A&` in `B`'s constexpr constructor -- passing by value fixes the problem.
What is happening there?

g++ version: `(Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0`.
It was the same on some older version too.

This problem doesn't occur when compiling with clang-10.

Comment: Why not report this to the g++ engineers?  I'm sure they have a bug ticket system.

Comment: Tip: In C++ try and use `const` instead of `#define`.

Comment: It's worth exploring how this memory footprint scales vs. various values of `N` as this could be accidentally quadratic.

Comment: For the record, it occurs with g++ 10.2.0 on Arch as well.

Comment: Memory usage scales linearly with number of iterations in B's constructor, so it seems it is quadratic (I mean size of A times number of iterations). Will try to file a ticket later

Comment: @w0nsh -- If you show them your program, plus show what other compilers are doing, I am confident they will look into the issue quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be fixed in versions 10.3 and 11.

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96197